# Literal not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am kinda new so still learning. I have an AJAX timer that ticks every second querying a database with a SELECT.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SongTimer"
            EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate runat="server">
        <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="SongTimer" Enabled="false" OnTick="SongTimer_Tick" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional" ID="updateVid">

    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="player"></div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SongTimer"
                EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnVideoID" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
            <asp:Literal ID="litVideo" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I then ask if a hidden field set by a script contained within a literal is equal to the value returned by the database.

```
protected void SongTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    utils util = new utils();
    string[] IDs = util.GetCurrentVideo(Convert.ToInt32(GroupID)).Split('=');
    foreach (string id in IDs)
    {
        if (!id.Contains(".com"))
        {
            VideoID = id;
        }

    }

    if (hdnVideoID.Value.Contains(VideoID))
    {
        return;
    }
    else {
        hdnVideoID.Value = util.GetCurrentVideo(Convert.ToInt32(GroupID));
        btnJoin_Click(null, null);
        lblLink.Text = VideoID;
    }

}
```

Every time the database changes it does go through to my breakpoints and goes over my functions which change the video by changing a script, however, nothing happens on the client, even though the literal running the script should be changed. The hidden field controls are set to static so are referenced just fine in the script. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

```
public void btnJoin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateFeed();

    SongTimer.Enabled = true;

}

public void UpdateFeed()
{
    utils util = new utils();
    util.GetGroupDetails(Request.Params["id"].ToString(), ref GroupName, ref GroupDescription, ref ww, ref CurrentVideo, ref CurrentTimeFrame);
    lblLink.Text = CurrentVideo;
    hdnNewVideo.Value = CurrentVideo;
    string FullURL = CurrentVideo;
    hdnHasChanged.Value = "N";
    string[] IDs = FullURL.Split('=');
    CurrentTimeFrame = CurrentTimeFrame + 3.0;
    VideoID = "";
    foreach (string id in IDs)
    {
        if (!id.Contains(".com"))
        {
            VideoID = id;
        }

    }
    string b = "";
    b += "<script>";
    b += "      var tag = document.createElement('script');";
    b += "";
    b += "      tag.src = \"https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api\";";
    b += "      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];";
    b += "      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);";
    b += "";
    b += "      var player;";
    b += "      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {";
    b += "        player = new YT.Player('player', {";
    b += "          height: '390',";
    b += "          width: '100%',";
    b += "          videoId: '" + VideoID + "',";
    b += "          events: {";
    b += "            'onReady': onPlayerReady,";
    b += "            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange";
    b += "          }";
    b += "        });";
    b += "      }";
    b += "";
    b += "      function onPlayerReady(event) {";
    b += "        event.target.playVideo();";
    b += "      }";
    b += "      var done = false;";
    b += "      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {";
    b += "        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {";
    b += "          GetCurrentTime();";
    b += "          SetTime();";
    b += "          done = true;";
    b += "        }";
    b += "      }";
    b += "      function stopVideo() {";
    b += "        player.stopVideo();";
    b += "      }";
    b += "function SetTime(){player.seekTo(" + CurrentTimeFrame + ")}";
    b += "function GetCurrentTime() {";
    b += "            var CurrentTime = player.getCurrentTime();";
    b += "            var CurrentVideo = player.getVideoUrl();";
    b += "";
    b += "            document.getElementById('hdnTimeStamp').value = CurrentTime;";
    b += "            document.getElementById('hdnVideoID').value = CurrentVideo;";
    b += "        }";
    b += "    </script>";
    litVideo.Text = b;
    updpnl.Update();
}
```

Comment: Where is the `litVideo` and `updpnl`?

Comment: thanks and sorry, I have included the elements in the updated post. They are placed before </asp:content>